# Replacing a captured group using SED

Tags: sed

> xxxxxx15  |xxxxxx02|RM99999             |xxxxx                                   |Ankur                    |xxxxx                         |xxxxxxxx|M|xxxxxxxx|        |     |        |xxxxxxx|xxx|xxxxxxxx|        |10   |New York|  23.00|F|P| |    |NA

Want to replace 10 with 65, closet I got is `sed -i '/^.\{20\}RM99999/ s/^\(?:[^|]*\|\)\{16\}\([^|]*\)/\165/' test.txt`

But it replaces, the first character with 65 (`RM99999` can be in more locations, but need to replace the line which has `RM99999` on 20th character)

Comment: can you provide a line with expected output ?

Answer (score 5):

looks like a XY problem.

why not try with awk ?

```
awk -F\| -v OFS=\| '$3=="RM99999" && $17 == 10 { $17=65 } {print ; } '
```

where

- `-F\|` tell awk to use | as field separator (`\` tell shell to escape `|` )
- `-v OFS=\|` tell awk to use | as the field separator when records are output
- `$3=="RM99999" && $17 == 10` select line with third filed as RM99999 and seventeenth as 10
- `$17 = 65` replace by 65
- `{ print ; }` print all pattern, changed and unchanged

Answer (score 5):

```sh
sed '/^.\{19\}RM99999/s/10/65/' <in >out
```

Will replace the first occurrence of the string *10* with the string *65* on a line where the string *RM99999* begins at the 20th character.

I guess some think the 17th field should be replaced. I really don't understand why because I can't see it in the question, but if it is what you want...

```sh
sed '/^.\{19\}RM99999/s/[^|]*/65/17' <in >out
```

...that will replace the 17th `|` delimited field with the string *65* on a line where the string *RM99999* begins at the 20th character.

I'm kinda just grabbing at straws, but maybe they mean only 10 and only in the 17th field, and only on lines where *RM99999* starts 20 chars in? It's a little more difficult...

```sh
sed -e'/^.\{19\}RM99999/s/|/|\n/16' \
    -e's/\n\([^|]*\)10/\165/;s/\n//' <in >out
```

...but that will do it. Come to think of it, it does look *a little* more like your own code. Maybe it's what's wanted after all.

This one's a little more direct...

```sh
sed -e'/^.\{19\}RM99999/!b'    \
    -e's/|\([^|]*10\)*/&\n/16' \
    -e's/10\n/65/;s/\n//'
```

And this does it in one go - if the field count is fixed, that is.

```sh
sed -e'/^.\{19\}RM99999/s/10\([^|]*\(|[^|]*\)\{7\}\)$/65\1/'
```

You could do the same thing from the front end of course...

```sh
sed -e'/^.\{19\}RM99999/s/^\([^|]*\(|[^|]*\)\{16\}\)10/\165/'
```

But as there are as half as many fields to the tail, it's probably better not to if it can be helped.

And it's a little easier to write with Extended regexp syntax:

```sh
sed -Ee'/^.{19}RM99999/s/10([^|]*(\|[^|]*){7})$/65\1/'
```

Comment: I'm guessing that the questioner doesn't want to replace always the first `10`, but only in the 17th field?

Comment: @TobySpeight - where do you get that? I noticed in the other answer there seems to be a lot more understood about fields or whatever than I could do, but the only concrete interpretation of the question I could make was: replace 65 w/ 10 when only and exactly 19 chars precede RM9999.

Comment: @TobySpeight - is that what you're talking about?

Comment: And now you've run into the problem of the question - `\165` not being parsed as `\1` `65` as desired.  I'd suggest an interim replacement (e.g. `\1sixtyfive`) followed by a second stage of replacing `|sixtyfive|` with `|65|`. ...

Comment: ... if I didn't think the Awk solution a better tool for this job.

Comment: @TobySpeight - `\165` is parsed exactly as it should be. What does that mean? `\165` is the first capture group followed by the string 65. What do you think it is? And you're welcome to prefer any tool you like - I was just wondering if I missed something. I still don't see it asked for, though.